# Countdown calculate milliseconds

Tags: javascript, time, counter, countdown

I have a countdown script that allows me to count down to a certain time.

The time is calculated in milliseconds. 
I use a website to calculate the milliseconds to where I want the countdown to end, but I think this comes with a problem.

[Calculate milliseconds](http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/#.VdXYoVOqpBd)

If I do a test for a minute it runs behind (my computer hits the minute mark before the script does). This is probably because the milliseconds are calculated from the internal clock. If my clock is set different the milliseconds don't work right. (I hope)

So I thought I let the script calculate the milliseconds. This way it doesn't matter on what server the script runs it always takes the time from the internal clock of that server.

I have no idea how to calculate this. And this is where you come in :-)
I hope anybody can help me out here.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    FlipClock.Lang.Custom = { days:'Dagen', hours:'Uren', minutes:'Minuten', seconds:'Seconden' };
    var opts = {
        clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
        countdown: true,
        language: 'Custom'
    };  
    var countdown = 1440077820 - ((new Date().getTime())/1000); // from: 09/19/2015 07:19 pm +0200
    countdown = Math.max(1, countdown);
    $('.clock-builder-output').FlipClock(countdown, opts);
});
</script>
```

The problem is that I don't really understand JS....

M.

Comment: What are you trying to calculate? The number of milliseconds to a specific time?

Comment: Yes. The `var countdown` holds a number (milliseconds 1440077820) This is the date where the countdown should reach `0`. Minus the current date

Comment: In your example, `countdown` is in seconds, not milliseconds. Also, `new Date(1440077820 * 1000 )` says that the time of this is August 20th, 09:37:00 GMT-0400. Not sure if this is intentional, but seems like you're messing up your units.

Comment: Any reason you're hard coding the Date, btw?

Comment: You are right. It is in seconds.... crap. The date is correct! this is because I wanted to test if one minute countdown ends at the same time as my computer

Comment: Where am I hardcoding the date?

Comment: Haha that might be your problem. I'll post a little example down below where you can define the date and stuff so you can pick wherever you want the countdown to end

Comment: Was just talking about in ` var countdown = 1440077820 - ((new Date().getTime())/1000);`, the `1440077820`. But all good, I realize now that's the "one minute from now" part you were trying to test

Comment: Yes but can I make that number relative? I want to set a end date/time

Comment: Number of seconds remaining until August 30th, 2015 at 3:15

`Math.round((new Date(2015, 07, 30, 3, 15, 0).getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);`

Just change it to whatever date and time you want

Comment: @Unglückspilz Nice. But if I run this it sais 60 days in stead of 30 `var countdown = Math.round((new Date(2015, 09, 19, 19, 19, 19).getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);`

Comment: Months enumerate from 0 so 09 is October https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your example. This will countdown in seconds to August (months enumerate from 0) 30th 2015, at 3:15

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    FlipClock.Lang.Custom = { days:'Dagen', hours:'Uren', minutes:'Minuten', seconds:'Seconden' };
    var opts = {
        clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
        countdown: true,
        language: 'Custom'
    };

    var dateTo = new Date(2015, 07, 30, 3, 15, 0);
    var countdown = Math.round((dateTo.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
    $('.clock-builder-output').FlipClock(countdown, opts);
});
</script>
```